# Android screen orientation use different xmls (switching/rotating screen landscape and portrait)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

I want to develop an android application for perfectly screen design arranged for portrait and landscape modes. and should have to give the screen orientation facility to user.
how to change two xml files of the application when change the screen orientation of the device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create another layout folder called **layout-Land** under the res folder.
copy all landscape xml files to that layout -Land folder with the same name.
Recheck all portrait xml files are in the layout folder.
add
`android:configChanges="orientation"` to the manifest

```
 <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

do not add `android:configChanges="orientation"` it'll stop recreation of activity which ultimately not allows you to have `vertical` and `horizontal` layout applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Just make another layout and put it in your `layout-land` folder. Your structure should look like this:

```
res/
    layout/ 
        my_layout.xml #will be used in portrait
    layout-land/ 
        my_layout.xml #will be used in landscape
```

Do not add the `android:configChanges` attribute as suggested -- as @nitin said, that will prevent your `Activity` from being recreated and you'll have to do some extra work to handle resource switching. When your `Activity` is created, and you create the layout (e.g. `setContentView(R.layout.my_layout.xml)`, it will resolve the right layout resource based on the orientation.

Answer (score -2):

Add this code in manifest file in activity tag:

For landscape mode:

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity"
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
</activity>
```

For portrait mode:

```
<activity android:name="MyActivity"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
</activity>
```